# how to write multiple inputs to text file using append in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

```
while True:
    def student_info(name,age,gender):
        print("The student name is:",name)
        print("The student age is:",age)
        print("The student gender is:",gender)
    print("*"*70)
    Student_name=input("Enter Student name:")
    Student_age=input("Enter Student age:")
    Student_gender=input("Enter Student gender:")


    print("*"*70)

    with open('Try1.txt', 'w') as f:
      f.write(Student_name+" "+Student_age+" "+Student_gender)


    student_info(Student_name,Student_age,Student_gender)

    print("if you want add more students press 1 ")
    user_input=input("Enter:")
    if user_input=="1":

        with open('Try1.txt', 'a') as f:
          f.write(Student_name+" "+Student_age+" "+Student_gender)
        student_info(Student_name,Student_age,Student_gender)
```

I want to add more students to the text, but when I add one more the previous one removes.. I need help in this please.

Comment: You do not write linebreaks - so all students stay in one line which makes it hard to read them back.  You also get into problems if you want to read it back if any Student has a name that contains spaces ( `Reinhard Urlich Nikolas von Hohenstauffen zu Ulm 24 male` ) - it would be difficult to get that back conceisly.

Comment: Nice read: [Falsehoods programmers believe about names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need a `break` at some point, in the case the user does not input a 1, and you want to `continue` looping otherwise. And also you where duplicating the data insertion at the end of your code.

Try this instead:

```
while True:
    def student_info(name,age,gender):
        print("The student name is:",name)
        print("The student age is:",age)
        print("The student gender is:",gender)
    print("*"*70)
    Student_name=input("Enter Student name:")
    Student_age=input("Enter Student age:")
    Student_gender=input("Enter Student gender:")


    print("*"*70)

    with open('Try1.txt', 'a') as f:
      f.write('\n'+Student_name+" "+Student_age+" "+Student_gender)


    student_info(Student_name,Student_age,Student_gender)

    print("if you want add more students press 1 ")
    user_input=input("Enter:")
    if user_input=="1": continue
    else: break
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the first `open` is inside the `while` loop, just take it outside. Hre I reformat your code:

```
def student_info(name,age,gender):
    print("The student name is:",name)
    print("The student age is:",age)
    print("The student gender is:",gender)

while True:
    print("*"*70)
    Student_name=input("Enter Student name:")
    Student_age=input("Enter Student age:")
    Student_gender=input("Enter Student gender:")


    print("*"*70)

    with open('Try1.txt', 'a') as f:
      f.write(f"{Student_name} {Student_age} {Student_gender}")

    student_info(Student_name, Student_age, Student_gender)

    print("if you want add more students press 1 ")
    user_input=input("Enter:")
    if user_input != "1":
        break
```